# Why spring data jpa not issuing JOIN query?

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have created two entities `Book` and `Book_Category` with one-to-many relationship. When I issued `BookCategoryRepository.findAll()`, I expected hibernate to use 'INNER JOIN' query. But it just issued query to take data from Book_Category.

What I am missing?  What should I do to make hibernate issue JOIN query?

Book.java

```
@Entity
public  class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_category_id")
    private BookCategory bookCategory;
}
```

BookCategory.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book_category")
public  class BookCategory {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookCategory", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Book> books;
}
```

BookCategoryRepository.java

```
public  interface BookCategoryRepository extends JpaRepository<BookCategory, Integer> {
}


bookCategoryRepository.findAll()
```

Comment: The join happens since you have that on the entity. the entity BookCategory also has a set of Books so when you do findAll() you should be receiving a set of books as well. What is it that you are trying to achieve here. You can write a @query if you really need to see JOIN in the query.

Comment: Hibernate is issuing only select * from Book_category. I expect it to issue select * from book_Category inner join Book b.  I have already set FetchType to eager. So I don't want to use @Query.

Comment: @GrinishNepal `@query` is also not working on that case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hibernate uses by default a second query to retriev the child collection. One reason for this is a proper limit query. Otherwise, there would be more rows in the result set, than entities for the 1 side, if at least one has more than 1 child.

There exists an annotation to change this behaviour in hibernate which is ignored by the Spring Data Jpa Repositories. The annotation is `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)`. You might consider [How does the FetchMode work in Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602386/how-does-the-fetchmode-work-in-spring-data-jpa) if you really need this behaviour.