# How to configure Spring boot for work with two databases?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I am using **Spring Boot 2.X** with **Hibernate 5** to connect two different MySQL databases (Bar and Foo) *on different servers*. I am trying to list all the information of an entity (own attributes and `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` relations) from a method in a REST Controller.

I have followed several tutorials to do this, thus, I am able to get all the information for my `@Primary` database (Foo), however, I always get an exception for my secondary database (Bar) when retrieving the `@OneToMany` sets. If I swap the `@Primary` annotation to the Bar database, I able to get the data from the Bar database but not for the Foo database . Is there a way to resolve this?

This is the exception I am getting:

```
...w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver :
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: 
    Could not write JSON document: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: 
        com.foobar.bar.domain.Bar.manyBars, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]-com.foobar.bar.domain.Bar["manyBars"]); 
    nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
        failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: 
        com.foobar.bar.domain.Bar.manyBars, could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.foobar.bar.domain.Bar["manyBars"])
```

My application.properties:

```
# MySQL DB - "foo"
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://XXX:3306/foo?currentSchema=public
spring.datasource.username=XXX
spring.datasource.password=XXX
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
# MySQL DB - "bar"
bar.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://YYYY:3306/bar?currentSchema=public
bar.datasource.username=YYYY
bar.datasource.password=YYYY
bar.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
# JPA
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

My `@Primary` DataSource configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.foobar.foo.repo"})
public class FooDbConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.foobar.foo.domain")
                .persistenceUnit("foo")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

My secondary DataSource configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "barEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "barTransactionManager", basePackages = {"com.foobar.bar.repo"})
public class BarDbConfig {

    @Bean(name = "barDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bar.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "barEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean barEntityManagerFactory(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("barDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.foobar.bar.domain")
                .persistenceUnit("bar")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "barTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager barTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("barEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory barEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(barEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

The REST Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class FooBarController {

    private final FooRepository fooRepo;
    private final BarRepository barRepo;

    @Autowired
    FooBarController(FooRepository fooRepo, BarRepository barRepo) {
        this.fooRepo = fooRepo;
        this.barRepo = barRepo;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    public List<Foo> listFoo() {
        return fooRepo.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/bar")
    public List<Bar> listBar() {
        return barRepo.findAll();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/foobar/{id}")
    public String fooBar(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {
        Foo foo = fooRepo.findById(id);
        Bar bar = barRepo.findById(id);

        return foo.getName() + " " + bar.getName() + "!";
    }

}
```

The Foo/Bar repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
  Foo findById(Integer id);
}

@Repository
public interface BarRepository extends JpaRepository<Bar, Long> {
  Bar findById(Integer id);
}
```

The entities for the `@Primary` datasource. The entities of the second datasource are the same (only changing the class names):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "foo")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"foo"})
    private Set<ManyFoo> manyFoos = new HashSet<>(0);

    // Constructors, Getters, Setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "many_foo")
public class ManyFoo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"manyFoos"})
    private Foo foo;

    // Constructors, Getters, Setters
}
```

Finally, my application main:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**It is important to remark that the solution should keep the Lazy property for both databases in order to maintain an optimal performance.**

**Edit 1:** If both catalogs ("databases" in MySQL terminology) are in same database ("server") the Rick James solution works!!

**The problem remains** when catalogs (MySQL databases) are in different databases (servers) and it is tried to keep Lazy  the property

Many thanks.

Comment: which controller method throws this exception? "/foobar/{id}" ?

Comment: @hovanessyan all methods retrieving OneToMany objects from the second database (Bar), for example "/bar". According to your second question, the method  "/foobar/{id}" does not throw any exception because it only returns the name of the object bar not the ManyToOne Foo foo.

Comment: Can you also please post your repositories?

Comment: I edited the question to include both repositories.

Answer (score 10):

*ToMany Collections are lazy by default in Hibernate & JPA.  The error is because Jackson is trying to serialize the OneToMany when the entity manager (aka session in hibernate-speak) is closed.  Hence, lazy collections cannot be retrieved.

Spring Boot with JPA by default provides an `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` for the primary EM.  This allows for read-only DB access, but, by default only works for the primary EM.

You have 3 options:

1) You can add a join fetch, e.g. [How does the FetchMode work in Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602386/how-does-the-fetchmode-work-in-spring-data-jpa#29667050)

2) You can add a OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter for the non primary entity manager and add it to your context.

Please note that this implies a challenge, for each Bar and Foo instance, your app will go back to the database to retrieve the OneToMany. This is the part that isn't working for Bar, but is for Foo.  This implies a scalability problem (called the N + 1 problem by some) as for each foo and bar, you run an additional query, which will get slow for non-trivial amounts of Foos and Bars.

3) An alternative is to make your collection on Bar and Foo eager (see this https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#fetch-- ) but this needs to be analyzed carefully if scalability is a concern at all for you.

I'd recommend option #1.

Comment: open session in view and Eager fetch are anti-patterns. JoinFetch should be utilized instead.

Comment: Not sure open session in view is an anti pattern, it's default spring boot behaviour, though it sets one up for N + 1.  Regardless, added join fetch, thanks for the input.

Comment: might be of interest https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/

Comment: Many Thanks!! I know that eager its a posible soultion, but only for tiny databases. If you have one object with one mille of join objects, this is not a good idea. I try to mantain the lazy property for the two dabases. I try to find a solution similar to having both databases as primary databases. I'm going to edit the question to add this.

Comment: Actually, at large volumes, lazy presents a different, some would say worse challenge.  For each Foo or Bar, you'll run a query to db, one bigger query is generally better than many smaller ones.

Answer (score 2):

**Two databases (aka "catalogs") on the same server?**  Use only one connection.  Then reference thus:

```
Foo.table1
Bar.table2
```

Use that syntax wherever you would have a simple table name.

**Different servers**

It gets messy if the data is not in the same machine.  A couple of ideas:

- Fetch the data from each catalog, then manipulate in application code.  The framework probably has no hooks for doing anything to both servers at the same time.
- Use MariaDB and its `FEDERATEDX` Engine.

Comment: Thanks! It is a great solution if both databases are in the same server, but not works if they are in different servers.

Comment: @Martin - If your question involves 2 different servers (or different instances of MySQL on a single server), the make that clear in your Question.  Your code sounds like both are connecting on localhost:3306, which is necessarily the _same_ instance on the _same_ server.

Comment: i copy it to give an example to replicate it (im not see that two databases are in same network). I edit the question to make that clear. But for next users that will read your question, its important to say that your example works if @Table(name="Foo" ,catalog="FooDB") and @Table(name="Bar" ,catalog="BarDB") it is added. Only if them are in the same databases. Many thanks!

Comment: @Martin - your changes were ambiguous, so I edited your question further.

Comment: @rick-james, for two different catalogs in same server it works, but is there a chance I can avoid the schema.table name and write only table name.

Comment: @SantosshKumhar - If you establish the "default database", then the syntax `table_name` is will use that 'database'.  I don't know how to establish the "default database" in your environment.  (In the commandline mysql tool:  `USE dbname;`)