# Can't get data for entity

Tags: jhipster

I use jhipster to generate 2 entity Employee and Department

and relationship:

- Employee.java

```
 @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "employees", allowSetters = true)
    private Department department;
```

- Department.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
```

and when I called api/employees , I had:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "code": "FU_EMP_DTP726",
    "name": "Concrete system",
    "birthDate": "2020-11-30",
    "address": "Granite frame",
    "phone": "0152104977",
    "salary": 65309.0,
    "department": {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "FU_DE_787778",
        "name": "Tools"
    }
}
```

but with api/departments , I had:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "code": "FU_DE_787778",
    "name": "Tools",
    "employees": null
}
```

I didn't know why department's employees is null

Comment: Probably because OneToMany is lazy fetched, have you considered defining an EntityGraph?
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph

Answer (score 0):

In bidirectional one-to-many relationship case jhipster do not get all ‘child’ form “One” side，because “N+1” problem .

For your purpose you need to be modify the generated code。use EntityGraph
modify repository、add a “employees” Set into ” DepartmentDTO“ and Mapper

[How to see both sides in one-to-many relationship generated by JHipster](http://How%20to%20see%20both%20sides%20in%20one-to-many%20relationship%20generated%20by%20JHipster)[How to see both sides in one-to-many relationship generated by JHipster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072544/how-to-see-both-sides-in-one-to-many-relationship-generated-by-jhipster)