# Recursive relationship in Spring Data and JPA?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

My `Comment` entity is self-joined that has a `subComment` set.

```
@Entity
public class Comment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private String id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentComment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Comment> subComments = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
private Comment parentComment;
```

Here in my `addComment` method

```
public ResponseEntity<Comment> addComment(Comment comment) {
    Comment currComment = commentRepository.save(comment);
    if (currComment.getParentId() != null) {
        Comment parent = commentRepository.findById(currComment.getParentId()).orElse(null);
        if (parent != null) {
            parent.addSubComment(currComment);
            currComment.setParentId(parent.getId());
            currComment.setParentComment(parent);
            commentRepository.save(parent);
        }
    }
    Comment responseComment = commentRepository.save(currComment);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(responseComment);
}
```

When I tried to establish the reverse relationship (owning side),
`comment.setParentComment(parent);` causes the error

`comment.setParentComment(parent);` is causing an error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed`

Full Comment entity class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentComment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Comment> subComments = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
private Comment parentComment;

private boolean isParent;
private String parentId;

public String getParentId() {
    return parentId;
}

public void setParentId(String parentId) {
    this.parentId = parentId;
}

public Set<Comment> getSubComments() {
    return subComments;
}

public void setSubComments(Set<Comment> subComments) {
    this.subComments = subComments;
}

public Comment addSubComment(Comment comment) {
    this.subComments.add(comment);
    return this;
}

public Comment getParentComment() {
    return parentComment;
}

public void setParentComment(Comment parentComment) {
    this.parentComment = parentComment;
}

public boolean getIsParent() {
    return isParent;
}

public void setIsParent(boolean isParent) {
    this.isParent = isParent;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
@JsonBackReference
private Comment parentComment;
```

I added @JsonBackReference that solved the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed` error. The parent `Comment` is also able to see the `subComments` set.

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be over complicating it.

1) You have the `@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")` but that is redundant. That's what the foreign key references anyway so you don't need to be explicit about it. No worries, but don't write code you don't need.

2) If you have the parentId in the a new subComment you don't need to look it up and add it to the parent comment's list. The concept you're missing here is the "owning" entity concept. Look at the Javadoc for `mappedBy`. Since the `parentComment` field does the mapping it defines the owning entity. Granted, it's the same Entity, but the point is that it's the `parentComment` field that controls the persistence. You don't need to add anything to the `Set` of `subComments` in order for the relationship to be persisted. You can do so if you want but JPA will ignore it. You only need to set the `parentComment` field. E.g.

Edit: This example is with JPA instead of Spring Data, but it's the same under the hood.

Your entity needs only be:

```
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentComment")
    private Set<Comment> subComments;

    @ManyToOne
    private Comment parentComment;
```

and you use it like so:

```
private void run() {
    runWrite();
    runRead();
    Comment comment = new Comment();
    comment.setId(1);
    Comment subComment = new Comment();
    subComment.setParentComment(comment);
    runSaveSubComment(subComment);
    runRead();
}
private void runWrite() {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    tx = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        Comment comment = new Comment();
        Comment subComment = new Comment();
        subComment.setParentComment(comment);
        em.persist(comment);
        em.persist(subComment);

        tx.commit();
    } finally {
        emf.close();
    }        
}
private void runRead() {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    try {
        Comment comment = em.createQuery("select c from Comment c left join fetch c.subComments where c.id = :id", Comment.class).setParameter("id", 1).getSingleResult();
        System.out.println(comment + Arrays.toString( comment.getSubComments().toArray()) );
    } finally {
        emf.close();
    }
}
private void runSaveSubComment(Comment subComment) {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    tx = em.getTransaction();
    try {
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(subComment);
        tx.commit();
    } finally {
        emf.close();
    }        
}
```

or if you want to do with Spring Data.

```
Comment comment = new Comment();
Comment sub1 = new Comment();
sub1.setParentComment(comment);
repo.save(comment);
repo.save(sub1);
Comment parentComment = repo.fetchSubCommentsById(1);
System.out.println(parentComment + Arrays.toString(parentComment.getSubComments().toArray()));
Comment sub2 = new Comment();
sub2.setParentComment(parentComment);
repo.save(sub2);
parentComment = repo.fetchSubCommentsById(1);
System.out.println(parentComment + Arrays.toString(parentComment.getSubComments().toArray()));
// or 
Comment p = new Comment();
p.setId(1);
Comment sub3 = new Comment();
sub3.setParentComment(p);
repo.save(sub3);
parentComment = repo.fetchSubCommentsById(1);
System.out.println(parentComment + Arrays.toString(parentComment.getSubComments().toArray()));
```

Comment: Spot on with your comments. I'm using Spring boot though, is there any way to simplify?

Comment: I'm not, just using the id of the first parent that was written to the database which I happen to know is 1. Typically, the current Comment is sent to the view with its id and the id is returned from the view when a user adds a new sub-comment. So, instead of fetching the parent comment from the database with the id just make a new Comment and set the id from the view. The save() call doesn't care about any other fields of the parent comment so it saves you a database call. The spring example shows it being done both ways.

Comment: Also, the custom `fetchSubCommentsById` gets the parents AND the subComments, so be aware of that. Normally, if you just got a Comment from the database the subComments would not be filled out. If you tried to access them you would get a lazy initialization exception. The fetchSubCommentsById is not well named. I just copied the query from the JPA section to a custom method in the Repository interface. See fetchMode discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602386/how-does-the-fetchmode-work-in-spring-data-jpa.

Comment: @K Just a note, since it might be helpful for others: you can avoid the lazy init exception by annotating the method with @Transactional. Has something to do with the entities staying connected to the entity manager, allowing the entity manager to lazy load relations.