# One to One mapping is creating multiple queries

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

As there are 100 000 records so I need to fetch `top 10` records by joining two tables, am using `mssql` server,i have written `@Query`, but its making 11 queries for the same which is causing performance issue.

It is taking around `9-10 seconds`.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "TelevisionSource")
public class MyTelevisionSource {
    @Id
    private Long SourceId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "nvarchar2 (2000)")
    private String TvsourceLongName;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "nvarchar2 (2000)")
    private String TvsourceDisplayName;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "SourceId")
    private RCMSource rcmSource;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyTelevisionSource [SourceId=" + SourceId + ", TvsourceLongName=" + TvsourceLongName
                + ", TvsourceDisplayName=" + TvsourceDisplayName + ", rcmSource=" + rcmSource + "]";
    }

}

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name = "Source")
public class RCMSource {

    @Id
    private Long SourceId;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "nvarchar2 (2000)")
    private String SourceName;

}


Service layer
***************

@Service
public class TelevisionSourceService {

    @Autowired
    private TelevisionSourceRepository televisionSourceRepo;

    public List<MyTelevisionSource> getTelevisionSource(){
        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 10);
        Page<MyTelevisionSource> tvSource =  televisionSourceRepo.findAll(pageable);

        List<MyTelevisionSource> sourceList= tvSource.getContent();

        sourceList.forEach(System.out::println);

        return sourceList;

    }

}


Repo
****
public interface TelevisionSourceRepository extends JpaRepository<MyTelevisionSource, Long> {
    Page<MyTelevisionSource> findAll(Pageable pageable);

}
```

and also i tried by writing `@Query` for the same, but it is also making 11 queries,

```
@Query("select t from MyTelevisionSource t inner join RCMSource s ON s.SourceId = t.SourceId")
    Page<MyTelevisionSource> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

without using pageable, is there any other way to fetch top 10 records, by joining two tables

Hibernate:

```
select
    TOP(?) mytelevisi0_.SourceId as SourceId1_1_,
    mytelevisi0_.TvsourceDisplayName as Tvsource2_1_,
    mytelevisi0_.TvsourceLongName as Tvsource3_1_ 
from
    dbo.TelevisionSource mytelevisi0_ 
inner join
    dbo.Source rcmsource1_ 
        on (
            rcmsource1_.SourceId=mytelevisi0_.SourceId
        )
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    rcmsource0_.SourceId as SourceId1_0_0_,
    rcmsource0_.SourceName as SourceNa2_0_0_ 
from
    dbo.Source rcmsource0_ 
where
    rcmsource0_.SourceId=?
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    rcmsource0_.SourceId as SourceId1_0_0_,
    rcmsource0_.SourceName as SourceNa2_0_0_ 
from
    dbo.Source rcmsource0_ 
where
    rcmsource0_.SourceId=?
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    rcmsource0_.SourceId as SourceId1_0_0_,
    rcmsource0_.SourceName as SourceNa2_0_0_ 
from
    dbo.Source rcmsource0_ 
where
    rcmsource0_.SourceId=?
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    rcmsource0_.SourceId as SourceId1_0_0_,
    rcmsource0_.SourceName as SourceNa2_0_0_ 
from
    dbo.Source rcmsource0_ 
where
    rcmsource0_.SourceId=?
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    rcmsource0_.SourceId as SourceId1_0_0_,
    rcmsource0_.SourceName as SourceNa2_0_0_ 
from
    dbo.Source rcmsource0_ 
where
    rcmsource0_.SourceId=?
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    rcmsource0_.SourceId as SourceId1_0_0_,
    rcmsource0_.SourceName as SourceNa2_0_0_ 
from
    dbo.Source rcmsource0_ 
where
    rcmsource0_.SourceId=?
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    rcmsource0_.SourceId as SourceId1_0_0_,
    rcmsource0_.SourceName as SourceNa2_0_0_ 
from
    dbo.Source rcmsource0_ 
where
    rcmsource0_.SourceId=?
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    rcmsource0_.SourceId as SourceId1_0_0_,
    rcmsource0_.SourceName as SourceNa2_0_0_ 
from
    dbo.Source rcmsource0_ 
where
    rcmsource0_.SourceId=?
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    rcmsource0_.SourceId as SourceId1_0_0_,
    rcmsource0_.SourceName as SourceNa2_0_0_ 
from
    dbo.Source rcmsource0_ 
where
    rcmsource0_.SourceId=?
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    rcmsource0_.SourceId as SourceId1_0_0_,
    rcmsource0_.SourceName as SourceNa2_0_0_ 
from
    dbo.Source rcmsource0_ 
where
    rcmsource0_.SourceId=?
```

Hibernate:

```
select
    count(mytelevisi0_.SourceId) as col_0_0_ 
from
    dbo.TelevisionSource mytelevisi0_ 
inner join
    dbo.Source rcmsource1_ 
        on (
            rcmsource1_.SourceId=mytelevisi0_.SourceId
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `toString()` method of `MyTelevisionSource` entity have the `RCMSource`, it will make a query to get the object.

You can use `fetch` in your query to avoid this call

```
@Query("select t from MyTelevisionSource t join fetch t.rcmSource s ON s.SourceId = t.SourceId",
countQuery = "select count(t) from MyTelevisionSource t join t.rcmSource s ON s.SourceId = t.SourceId")
Page<MyTelevisionSource> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: this also creating 11 queries,

Comment: Can you provide some additional information on the query

Comment: i have pasted the queries in my question

Answer (score 0):

Of course it produces 11 queries - one query for the initial load and each one query for each lazily initialized `@OneToOne` relationship you access in `toString`. You can reduce the number of queries by fetching the relationship `EAGER` (which is its actual default) but which might produce additional side effects later, so please be aware:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "SourceId")
private RCMSource rcmSource;
```

Comment: i tried that also, still it is producing 11 queries.

As i am using pageable, is this making that issue.

How can fetch 10 records without using pageable??

I tried Limit and rowNum, both are not allowed in @Query

Comment: Please append the actual 11 queries to your question so we can see which one might be superfluous.

Comment: check, i have added in my question

Comment: Are these the same 11 queries when having `EAGER` loading set?

Comment: OK, this seems a Spring Data related problem, please check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602386/how-does-the-fetchmode-work-in-spring-data-jpa

Comment: what should be the next approach?