# Hibernite ignoring lazy fetchtype in relations onetomany and load collections

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading

in my web app on spring boot 2 i have an entity with ralations **onetomany**.
I do not want to receive these entities. but i get them.
i switched of **spring.jpa.open-in-view=false**.
in dao layer i use spring data jpa and methods **getById()**, **getAll()** .

my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project", schema = "ci_crm")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ProjectEntity {`

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private CompanyEntity company;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserEntity user;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    private List<MilestoneEntity> milestoneList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    private List<NotificationEntity> notificationList;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    private List<CommentEntity> commentList;
```

So, how fix it?

**the problem is solved:**
the problem was in service layaer. there was an annotation @Transactional throughout the class.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because of the way entity manager was created in your spring boot project. Spring-jpa creates the query using the entity manager and Hibernate will ignore the fetch mode if the query was built by the entity manager.

Please see the below topic

> How does the FetchMode work in Spring Data JPA - `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602386/how-does-the-fetchmode-work-in-spring-data-jpa`