# EAGER loading with one select doesn't work in Spring Data JPA

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

there is already a similar post. Since this is already older, I hope something has changed since then ([How does the FetchMode work in Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602386/how-does-the-fetchmode-work-in-spring-data-jpa))

I would like to run all jpa repository#findById in one select, if the relationship is marked with EAGER. However, spring data ignores the EAGER specification and the FETCH.JOIN annotation from hibernate.

Is there a generic solution that all findById queries are executed in one select?

I wouldn't want to write a separate JPL or EntityGraph for each query. Does anyone know a generic solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the FetchMode work in Spring Data JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602386/how-does-the-fetchmode-work-in-spring-data-jpa)

Comment: No, I hope there is a newer solution

Comment: There isn't, and if there were it still would be a duplicate. If you want to encourage new answers to an existing question you may start a bounty. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Ah shit started it on the wrong question :). How can i remove the bounty?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. I guess, you could post on meta and hope a moderator is able and willing to move it. I have no idea for the chances of that happening though.

Comment: Why not use a Set instead of a List?

Comment: I use a Set, but there is no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### JpaReposistory

The easiest option would be to write a `JpaRepository<T, Id>`. This is still a custom repository. However, you do not have to write so much code. You mainly have to write a repository interface for each relevant class and annotate the `findById(Long id)` method with a graph. The advantage is that if you edit your entity, the repository method will not need any changes because you define the entity graph within the entity class itself.

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "Department.detail",
                  attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode("employees"))
public class Department {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Employee> employees;

    // ...
}

public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "Department.detail", type = EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    List<Department> findById(Long id);
}
```

As Spring data ignores the `@Fetch(Fetchmode.JOIN)` annotation or the information `fetch = FetchType.EAGER`, you cannot influence the join how you want it to be within the entity itself.

### JPQL Query Where You Need It

Another option can be considered as a bad software engineering style: You can call the database queries directly where you need them. This means that you execute the code which you would usually write in the repository.

```
public ClassWithQueryResults {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void methodWhereYouNeedYourResults() {

        TypedQuery<Department> query = entityManager.createQuery(
                "SELECT DISTINCT d FROM Department d LEFT JOIN d.employees e",
                Department.class);
        List<Department> departments = query.getResultList();

        // ...
    }
}
```

### Repository With JPQL, Generics and Reflection

Taking the previously suggested idea, you can create a custom repository which is valid for all your entities. The first step would be to create an attribute in your entity class in which you store the attribute which should be fetched.

```
public class Department extends AbstractEntity {
    
    public static void String ATTRIBUTE_TO_FETCH = "employees";

    ...
}
```

With some tweaking, this can be extended to an array/list of all the fields which should be fetched. As this attribute is directly in your entity classes, the chance for any mistakes and future effort is low. Obviously, this attribute should have the same name in all your entities.

The next step would be to create the repository. I provide an example with the `findAll()` method. You have to pass it only the class name of the entities you want to have and the generics and reflection do the rest. (Consider what you want to do with the exceptions.)

```
public <T> List<T> findAll(Class<T> tClass) 
        throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {

    String className = tClass.getSimpleName();

    String attributeToFetch = (String) 
    tClass.getDeclaredField("ATTRIBUTE_TO_FETCH").get(null);

    String queryString = String.format("SELECT DISTINCT p FROM %s p LEFT JOIN p.%s c", 
            className, attributeToFetch);

    TypedQuery<T> query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, tClass);

    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Depending on how you want to implement this, the modification/generation of a query through simple manipulation of a String can offer the possibility of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am familiar with this option, but I have to do this separately for each entity and that is exactly what I would like to avoid.

Comment: @MelleD For the first suggestion with the entity graph, this really results in the creation of a specific class for each entity class. However, the second solution is not very specific for each entity class. The relevant information is the class name of your entity class and the name of the attributes which have to be fetched. Above, I added a method which inserts these information at the correct position (see under "Repository With JPQL, Generics and Reflection"). However, you still have to provide the information about the class where you want to get the entities from.

Comment: It won't work that way, the query is too simple for that
One way could be via refection or perhaps with a own annotation via the Criteria API, because there are more then one JOIN.

Comment: @MelleD I never tried this but would it not be possible to add multiple joins to the query? You could just loop over there variable you want to execute joins for.

Comment: Maybe i should just use entityManager.find( getDomainClass(), id) then it works